# Commutative matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Given two 3x3 matrix:

$$
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 9 \cr
6 & 4 & -18 \cr
-3 & 0 & 13 \cr
\end{bmatrix}\quad
W=
\begin{bmatrix}
13 & 9 & 3 \cr
-14 & -8 & 2 \cr
5 & 3 & -1 \cr
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Is there any way to predict that $ V * W = W * V $
without actually calculating both multiplications

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for Math StackExchange, not MathOverflow. This site is for research questions in mathematics.

Comment: It's a good question, but as walkar says, it is unfortunately outside the scope of MO. Would you like it migrated? (PS there is, but you still have to work for it)

Comment: thank you, i flag this question to migration to Math StackExchange

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by predict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is interesting because multiplying $3\times 3$ matrices requires so few operations that it's very hard to find anything that beats the naive method  in terms of number of multiplications!

---

For $n$ relatively small, multiplying two $n\times n$ matrices together requires $n^3$ multiplications, so computing both $UV$ and $VU$ requires $2n^3$ multiplications.

One way that we can improve on this is by checking if $UVx = VUx$ for a random vector $x$.
If $U$ and $V$ commute then this inequality will hold.

On the other hand, if $x$ has a continuous distribution with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf{R}^n$, then
$$
\Pr(UVx = VUx)
= \Pr(x \in \ker(UV - VU)).
$$

Since the kernel of $UV - VU$ is a subspace, if $UV \neq VU$, then $\Pr(x \in \ker(UV - VU)) = 0$.

Now, computing $UVx$ requires $n^2$ multiplications to compute $Vx$ and then $n^2$ more multiplications to compute $U(Vx)$ and vice versa for $VUx$.
Thus, checking if $UVx = VUx$ requires $4n^2$ multiplications.

When $n = 3$, this is $4\cdot 3^2 = 36$ multiplications compared to $2\cdot 3^3 = 54$ multiplications required to compute $UV$ and $VU$.
This speed-up gets more pronounced as $n$ grows.

Of course, if we're counting multiplications so closely, it may not be so cheap so sample a random $x$.
Probably the cheapest way to do it would be to sample three independent $U(0, 1)$ entries, which is very fast, but probably not as fast as $54 - 36 = 18$ multiplications.

There's also the fact that your matrices are integer matrices, so computing $UV$ and $VU$ costs $54$ integer multiplications, which would most likely be faster than $36$ floating point multiplications required to compute $UVx$ and $VUx$.

Answer (score 2):

Two matrices commute if and only if they have a same Jordan basis. This is important theoretically, but finding a Jordan basis is usually harder then multiplying directly and checking that they commute.